# Grunt + Compass doesn't create CSS File

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, grunt-contrib-compass

I get the following error when using `grunt compass`:

"You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory."

I tried it with grunt 3 different ways. More below.

**My folder structure:**

```
test \
     Gruntfile.js
     package.json
     \ node_modules \
     \ _src \ (this is the root folder of my Jekyll site)
        \ config.rb
        \ index.html
        \ static/
            \ _sass \
            \ css \
            \ images \
            \ js \
```

---

### What works:

Everything works fine **without** using `grunt` and using `/_src/config.rb`:

```
#project_path = "_src/"
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
css_path = "static/" + css_dir
sass_dir = "_sass"
sass_path = "static/" + sass_dir
images_dir = "images"
images_path = "static/" + images_dir
output_style = :expanded
relative_assets = true
line_comments = false
```

So, in `/src` I can compile just fine with `compass watch`.

---

### What doesn't work

Anyway, I decided to ditch all GUI apps and step it up with `grunt`. That's where the problems started.

I'm also up to date:

```
$ grunt --version
>> grunt-cli v0.1.13

$ npm -v
>> 1.4.3

$ node -v
>> v0.10.26
```

#### 1st try

The first thing I tried was trying to use the existing `config.rb`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        // Config
        watch: {
            compass: {
                files: ['**/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:dev']
            },
            js: {
                // PLACEHOLDER HERE
            }
        },
        compass: {
            dev: {
                // dev options
                // ↓↓↓ HERE'S THE COMPASS CONFIG FILE ↓↓↓
                options: { config: '_src/config.rb' }
            },
            prod: {
                // prod options
            },
        },
        jshint: {
            options: { jshintrc: '.jshintrc' },
            all: ['Gruntfile.js', '_src/static/js/*.js']
        },
        browserSync: {
            files: {
                src : [
                    '_src/static/css/*.css',
                    '_src/static/images/*',
                    '_src/static/js/*.js',
                    '_src/**/*.html'
                ],
            },
            options: {
                watchTask: true
            }
        }
    });
    // Load the Grunt plugins.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compress');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');
    // Register the default tasks.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['compass:dev', 'browserSync', 'watch']);
    grunt.registerTask('prod', ['compass:prod']);
};
```

Running `grunt` from `/test` works without an error, it even recognizes file changes, but doesn't compile my sass. No css file gets created.

I tried `grunt compass watch --verbose` and it aborts:

```
Running "compass:prod" (compass) task
Verifying property compass.prod exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: cssDir=["_src/static/css"], sassDir=["_src/static/_sass"], imagesDir=["_src/static/images"], javascriptsDir=["_src/static/js"], fontsDir=["_src/static/fonts"], outputStyle="compressed", relativeAssets="true", noLineComments="true"
Options: cssDir=["_src/static/css"], sassDir=["_src/static/_sass"], imagesDir=["_src/static/images"], javascriptsDir=["_src/static/js"], fontsDir=["_src/static/fonts"], outputStyle="compressed", relativeAssets="true", noLineComments="true", time
You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.
Warning: ↑ Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

**… which I don't get at all.**

#### 2nd try – preferred attempt

Since I don't like having the `config.rb` sitting around in `/_src/` anyway, I deleted it and replaced `options: { config: '_src/config.rb' }` in `Gruntfile.js` with:

```
options: {
    //config: '_src/config.rb'
    cssDir: ['_src/static/css'],
    sassDir: ['_src/static/_sass'],
    imagesDir: ['_src/static/images'],
    javascriptsDir: ['_src/static/js'],
    fontsDir: ['_src/static/fonts'],
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    relativeAssets: 'true',
    noLineComments: 'false'
}
```

The error is exactly the same as the former one:

> You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.

#### 3rd try

As a last resort I tried putting the `config.rb` in the root (`/test`) add `project_path = "_src"` to it and use `options: { config: 'config.rb' }` in the Gruntfile. This did work as poor as my other trials.

I'd really like the Gruntfile-only version to work. I guess the base path for compass isn't working out too well, but can't figure out what to do.

---

### Excerpt of what I already read on StackExchange to solve this

I already read:

- [build automation - Grunt compass task not compatible with this directory structure? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921132/grunt-compass-task-not-compatible-with-this-directory-structure)

  - tried the `relativeAssets: 'false'` trick
- [sass - "You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory" error with compass project - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123557/you-must-compile-individual-stylesheets-from-the-project-directory-error-with)

  - No new ideas here. My directories are all different for Sass, CSS, JS etc.
- [build automation - Grunt compass task not compatible with this directory structure? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921132/grunt-compass-task-not-compatible-with-this-directory-structure)

  - Very similar to my problem. But the OP wanted to use the `config.rb` file and preferred to have it within his folder structure.
- [sass - "You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory" error with compass project - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123557/you-must-compile-individual-stylesheets-from-the-project-directory-error-with)

  - A compass-only question with `compass init` as the solution. Still, my compass works when used without grunt. So I dismissed this one.

PS: I also use RVM and Git. But I guess these don't matter here.

---

## **UPDATE:**

Small steps… some progress (not really):

`/Gruntfile.js`

```
compass: {
    dev: {
        // dev options
        options: {
            config: 'config.rb',
            cssDir: '_src/static/css',
            sassDir: '_src/static/_sass'
        }
    },
```

I don't get why adding the config.rb (instead of writing it all down like in "2nd try" above changes everything and grunt decides to finally output an css file.

`/config.rb`

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "static/css"
sass_dir = "static/_sass"
images_dir = "static/images"
javascript_dir = "static/js"
fonts_dir = "static/fonts"
relative_assets = false
```

SASS:

```
.logo {
    background-image: image-url($logo);
    //width: image-width($logo);
    //height: image-height($logo);
}
```

Rendered CSS:

```
// relative_assets = true
// image still shows up, but it's not the sites root
// /test/_src/static/images ==> _src should be the root
background-image: url('../../../static/images/gaya-design-logo.png');

// relative_assets = false
background-image: url('/static/images/gaya-design-logo.png');
```

I also get an error:

```
WARNING: 'gaya-design-logo.png' was not found (or cannot be read) in /Users/pattulus/Sites/test/static/images
```

That's "fine" since I also get this one when using regular `compass watch`. However, with grunt, when I uncomment the two lines in the SASS code it aborts spitting out this:

```
Errno::ENOENT on line ["28"] of /Users/pattulus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@test/gems/compass-0.12.6/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/image_size.rb: No such file or directory - /Users/patte/Sites/test/static/images/gaya-design-logo.png
```

Strange since "normal compass" works. I didn't install compass globally, the gem is only active in this project folder. So that possibility is ruled out.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728908/unable-to-compile-an-existing-project-because-compass-cant-find-it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end (and after a day of trial and error) it boiled down to setting relativeAssets to false.

My mistake with the "2nd try" was putting the boolean values in like this `relativeAssets: 'false',` instead of `relativeAssets: false,`.

That and some tweaking `basePath` and "more".

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // Config
        watch: {
            compass: {
                files: ['**/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:dev']
            },
        },

        compass: {
            dev: {
                // dev options
                options: {
                    httpPath: '/',
                    basePath: '_src',
                    cssDir: 'static/css',
                    sassDir: 'static/_sass',
                    imagesDir: 'static/images',
                    javascriptsDir: 'static/js',
                    fontsDir: 'static/fonts',
                    outputStyle: 'expanded',
                    relativeAssets: false,
                    noLineComments: false
                }
            },
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            },
            all: ['Gruntfile.js', '_src/static/js/*.js']
        },
        browserSync: {
            files: {
                src : [
                    '_src/static/css/*.css',
                    '_src/static/images/*',
                    '_src/static/js/*.js',
                    '_src/**/*.html'
                ],
            },
            options: {
                watchTask: true
            }
        }

    });

    // Load the Grunt plugins.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compress');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');

    // Register the default tasks.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['compass:dev', 'browserSync', 'watch']);
    grunt.registerTask('prod', ['compass:prod']);
};
```

This sure was a long day… matter of fact I've been trying to get this running exactly like this since Friday (with browserSync and the whole loot). Hope the helps the next fellow.